# WordPress updates defined vs add_filter?

Tags: plugin-development, updates, automatic-updates, options

I'm trying to create a WordPress update automation plugin. here I got two option to make enable and disable the updates.

1. Via define

ex :`defined( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED',true )`

2.via add_filter

ex:`add_filter( 'allow_major_auto_core_updates', '__return_true', 1 );`

my problem is 
if I have disabled the updates via `define` 
and also have enabled it via `add_filter` 
which one will work ? does `add_filter` override 'define'? or `define` override 'add_filter'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skimming through the `Core_Upgrader::should_update_to_version()` method, it looks like we **can override** the

```
 defined( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE' )    // true (all), false, minor
```

check, used to setup the local *boolean* variables`$upgrade_dev`, `$upgrade_minor` and  `$upgrade_major`, with the following filters:

```
...
apply_filters( 'allow_dev_auto_core_updates',   $upgrade_dev   ) 
...
apply_filters( 'allow_minor_auto_core_updates', $upgrade_minor )
...
apply_filters( 'allow_major_auto_core_updates', $upgrade_major )
...
```

So these filters have the *last word* over the `WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE` constant check.

Similarly, the `automatic_updater_disabled` filter can override the `AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED` constant check.

But note that we [can't override the constant itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931716/can-you-assign-values-to-constants-with-equal-sign-after-using-defined-in-php).